# Directory deleted after server reboot

Tags: centos, directory

I created a directory on the dev with the command mkdir /dev/hddbackup on CentOs powered server. After rebooting the server the directory is gone. I use the command ls to see it but it's not there. How do I make it stick?

Comment: Creating directory is not the solution as /dev stand for special devices and files which needs to be created using **"MAKEDEV or mknod"** . Once you create a device using makedev or mknod then it will be available after reboot too. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that your `/dev` tree is managed by `udev`, which means it is not persistent.

You can test this by looking at the output of "mount":

```
   steve@ssh ~ $ mount | grep /dev
   udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=191404,mode=755)
```

In that example you can see "`devtmpfs`", meaning the device-tree is stored in RAM and will disappear (and be recreated dynamically) on reboot.

Your best bet would be to add a cron-job, startup-script, or similar to create the missing entry.

Failing that add it in the start of your existing backup-script, where it will be used.

Comment: Instead of creating the directory each reboot, fix the main problem : don't put your backup directories in /dev.

Comment: Where should we make the directory then?

Comment: I personally use `/mnt/backups`, `/srv/backup` is also good.  "It depends" is the short answer.

Comment: @SteveKemp I'd avoid using `/mnt` though, since it's for mount points rather than actual files - even though I've never seen this, I don't see why a distro can't have `/mnt` in `tmpfs` since there's no actual data on it. @SoheilMirzaei `/backups` will be just fine.